# How do I turn a hash to a string in Puppet DSL?

Tags: ruby, puppet

I have a `hash` of hashes that I need to embed in an `exec` resource command. My thought was to serialize the `hash` to a `string` and interpolate it into the exec `call`. The `exec` call will be executing ruby code via `ruby -e 'ruby code here'`.

Using irb, I know that `hash.to_s` creates a single line parse-able version of the `hash`. Or I could use json. I doubt you can call `to_s` in puppet, but am not sure.

The stdlib for Puppet has `parseyaml` and `parsejson` to deserialize, but is there a way to serialize to a parse-able `string`? I can write a custom  puppet function to do it, but prefer an already built in solution if there is one.

**Update**
I am considering defining a puppet function. I have never written one before, so am not sure of the syntax. Here is my first attempt:

```
Puppet::Parser::Functions.newfunction(
    :serialize_hash, 
    :arity => 2,
    :doc => "Serialize a hash to any depth and optionally escape the double quotes.",
    :type => :rvalue) do |args| 
  hash = args[0]
  escape_quotes = args[1]
  serialized = hash.to_s
  if (escape_quotes)
    serialized.sub!(/"/, "\\\"")
  end
  serialized 
end
```

Comment: You begin your question asking about ruby's exec() method, then you finish your question asking about puppet.  My question is: what does your ruby exec() code have to do with puppet?

Comment: Because I am calling exec, I must pass my command to a shell invocation of ruby as a string. The hash from puppet must be serialized to a form that can be deserialized by ruby. It is a marshaling problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always execute ruby code inline with your puppet module:

```
$my_string = inline_template('<%= @my_hash.to_s %>')
```

Obviously it is important to not overuse this, but it is particularly useful when a very simple ruby function can achieve what you need.

Comment: Completely forgot about this feature! Thanks.