# Injecting facter into file content - no implicit conversion of Hash into String

Tags: puppet, facter

I want to inject some values from `facter <prop>` into a file content.

It works with `$fqdn` since `facter fqdn` returns **string**.

```
node default {
  file {'/tmp/README.md':
    ensure  => file,
    content => $fqdn, # $(facter fqdn)
    owner   => 'root',
  }

}
```

However, it does not work with hash object (`facter os`):

```
   node default {
      file {'/tmp/README.md':
        ensure  => file,
        content => $os, # $(facter os) !! DOES NOT WORK
        owner   => 'root',
      }

   }
```

And getting this error message when running `puppet agent -t`:

> Error: Failed to apply catalog: Parameter content failed on
>   File[/tmp/README.md]: Munging failed for value
>   {"architecture"=>"x86_64", "family"=>"RedHat", "hardware"=>"x86_64",
>   "name"=>"CentOS", "release"=>{"full"=>"7.4.1708", "major"=>"7",
>   "minor"=>"4"}, "selinux"=>{"config_mode"=>"enforcing",
>   "config_policy"=>"targeted", "current_mode"=>"enforcing",
>   "enabled"=>true, "enforced"=>true, "policy_version"=>"28"}} in class
>   content: no implicit conversion of Hash into String (file:
>   /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp, line:
>   2)

How to convert the hash to string inside the `pp` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I turn a hash to a string in Puppet DSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729033/how-do-i-turn-a-hash-to-a-string-in-puppet-dsl)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the linked issue. I will provide an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Puppet >= 4.5.0, it is now possible to natively convert various data types to strings in the manifests (i.e. in the pp files). The conversion functions are documented [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.4/function.html#conversion-to-string).

This would do what you want:

```
file { '/tmp/README.md':
  ensure  => file,
  content => String($os),
}
```

or better:

```
file { '/tmp/README.md':
  ensure  => file,
  content => String($facts['os']),
}
```

On my Mac OS X, that leads to a file with:

```
{'name' => 'Darwin', 'family' => 'Darwin', 'release' => {'major' => '14', 'minor' => '5', 'full' => '14.5.0'}}
```

Have a look at all that documentation, because there are quite a lot of options that might be useful to you.

Of course, if you wanted the keys inside the $os fact,

```
file { '/tmp/README.md':
  ensure  => file,
  content => $facts['os']['family'],
}
```

Now, if you don't have the latest Puppet, and you don't have the string conversion functions, the old way of doing this would be via templates and embedded Ruby (ERB), e.g.

```
$os_str = inline_template("<%= @os.to_s %>")
file { '/tmp/README.md':
  ensure => file,
  content => $os_str,
}
```

This actually leads to a slightly differently-formatted Hash since Ruby, not Puppet does the formatting:

```
{"name"=>"Darwin", "family"=>"Darwin", "release"=>{"major"=>"14", "minor"=>"5", "full"=>"14.5.0"}}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this works on any non obsolete Puppet and not just the latest Puppet.

Comment: The feature was introduced in Puppet 4.5.0. I just checked.